# maxRecordedDuration not accurate

Tags: avcapturesession

When creating a video with `AVCaptureSession` I am setting a `maxRecordedDuration` like so:

```
movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.0, 60)
```

I assume that this is supposed to stop the camera at 10.0 seconds of duration but it is not accurate. The final duration of the video is always like 10.034444 or for 5.0 seconds its like 5.36666666 etc.

Is there a more accurate way to set a limit when recording an output file capture session?